Jetpack compose. How to get Uri for a scaled image?
I'm trying to add the ability to zoom a picture. To do this I have a scalable container in which I want to put my Image. Here is my code:
@Composable
fun ZoomableContainer(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    minScale: Float,
    maxScale: Float,
    content: @Composable ZoomableContainerScope.() -> Unit
) {
    var scale by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(minScale) }
    var offsetX by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(RectangleShape)
            .onSizeChanged { size = it }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTransformGestures { _, pan, zoom, _ ->
                    scale = maxOf(minScale, minOf(scale * zoom, maxScale))
                    val maxX = (size.width * (scale - 1)) / 2
                    val minX = -maxX
                    offsetX = maxOf(minX, minOf(maxX, offsetX + pan.x))
                    val maxY = (size.height * (scale - 1)) / 2
                    val minY = -maxY
                    offsetY = maxOf(minY, minOf(maxY, offsetY + pan.y))
                }
            }
    ) {
        val scope = ZoomableContainerScope(scale, offsetX, offsetY)
        scope.content()
    }
}

I need to get Uri for a scaled image, that is, not for the original one, but for the scaled one, is it possible to do this?
Please, help me.

"is it possible to do this?" -- probably not. Very few sources of images also have the responsibility of scaling images. Have you investigated the existing implementations of image sub-sampling and zooming, such as https://saket.github.io/telephoto/, https://github.com/hehua2008/ComposeSubsamplingImage, and https://github.com/tom5079/Minamo?
